# How to do the android mobile web set up for robot framework?

Tags: android, robotframework, appium

I am getting following error

```
20141029 23:47:37.224 :  INFO : ${capabilities} = {}
20141029 23:47:37.228 :  INFO : 
Dictionary size is 4 and it contains following items:
browserName: Browser
deviceName: emulator-5554
platformName: Android
version: 4.4.2

20141029 23:47:37.229 :  INFO : ${executor} = http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
20141029 23:47:37.234 :  FAIL : No keyword with name 'Create Webdriver' found.
20141029 23:47:37.239 :  FAIL : No keyword with name 'Close All Browsers' found.
```

My set up look like this

```
Set Up Mobile Test Android
    ${capabilities}=    Create Dictionary
    Set To Dictionary    ${capabilities}    deviceName    AVD4.4.2
    Set To Dictionary    ${capabilities}    version    4.4.2
    Set To Dictionary    ${capabilities}    browserName    Browser
    Set To Dictionary    ${capabilities}    platformName    Android
    Log Dictionary    ${capabilities}
    ${executor}=    Evaluate    str('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub')

    Create Webdriver    Remote    desired_capabilities=${capabilities}    command_executor=${executor}
```

what should I need to do in order to run my tests on android web browser?

Comment: Have you included the relevant libraries in your suite setup? For example, does your suite setup table have `Library  Selenium2Library` in it?

Comment: you are right brian. My selenium lib got corrupted so had to reinstall. but I am still interested to the process on how to start a android emulator and browser using appium +robot framework